# trying to upload an image into canvas using button. But i get errors

Tags: python-2.7, tkinter

Exception in Tkinter callback:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "C:\Users\ANANTI\Anaconda2\lib\lib-tk\Tkinter.py", line 1542, in **call**
>      return self.func(*args)
>   File "C:/Users/ANANTI/Desktop/dataset/untitled8.py", line 50, in showImg
>       label = Label(master, image=photo)
>   NameError: global name 'master' is not defined

Comment: Could we see your code?

Comment: This error message seems very self-explanatory.

Answer (score 0):

The error message tells you exactly why the code isn't working. You have not defined `master`. You should put the name of the widget that you would like the `Label` to go (your canvas?) where `master` is.